# Why is this bitwise operation doesn't give expected output?

Tags: c, char, printf, unsigned, signed

In the 1st case o/p is 128 & 2nd case o/p is -128, why i am not getting same result?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char x=1;
    printf("%d",x<<7);
    return 0;
}
```

O/P  : 128

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char x=128;
    printf("%d",x);
    return 0;
}
```

O/P : -128